# HTTPS connection using PFX Certificate Thumbprint

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl-certificate, pem, pfx

I Need to connect into a server using a PFX certificate or PFX certificate thumbprint.

I've trying to find how to connect into my server using a PFX and there is nothing over internet can show me how to do it.

so far what I have is the usage of "requests" library (module), please see what i have so far:

```
 import requests
 requests.get("https://my.server.com/api/ping")

 output: 
 <Response [403]>
```

As far as I know, the 403 error code is due to server has rejected the connection, and I can understand that, it needs the certificate in order accept the connection.

Answer (score 3):

PFX is also called PKCS#12, so please have a look at the pkcs12 library for requests.

https://pypi.org/project/requests-pkcs12/

It adds the necessary parts and pieces to use PFX files instead of PEM files for requests.

e.g.

```
from requests_pkcs12 import get

r = get('https://example.com/test', pkcs12_filename='clientcert.p12',  pkcs12_password='correcthorsebatterystaple')
```

Comment: Thank you @schlenk it works, now I have as response '<Response [200]>', which I guess is "success", however, hoe I can get the actual response from the server (pong) ?

Comment: Hi @schlenk I have found the answer to my own question... what I did is to convert "r" into a json format. simple as r.json()